# jquery mail validation submits the form

Tags: php, jquery, email-validation

I have a jquery to validate my email id,but after validation it submits form instead of preventing it.

my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#personaledits').click(function(e) {
        $('#persemail').each(function(e) {
            email_address = $(this);
            email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
            if(!email_regex.test(email_address.val())){  alert('Please enter valid email'); e3.preventDefault(); return e.preventDefault(); return false; } 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // event is not required here
    $('#personaledits').click(function (e) {
        $('#persemail').each(function () {
            email_address = $(this);
            email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
            if (!email_regex.test(email_address.val())) {
                alert('Please enter valid email');
                e.preventDefault();    // You need to prevent the click event here
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#persemail').each(function(e) {
  email_address = $(this);
  email_regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
 });
```